# Send mail with generated pdf in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, tcpdf, dompdf

Is there any way to generate a pdf and send it in mail (without saving or with saving the generated pdf in specified directory) in codeigniter, I tried tcpdf and dompdf but unable to find solution.

Comment: I do this all the time with dompdf. Just save the generated file to a temporary directory, then send the email with the file attached, then delete the temporary file. The "how" is very dependent on how your site is set-up (i use mailgun to send the email and attaching a file is as simple as adding an additional field on the API request, but YMMV)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [mpdf and it's manual](https://mpdf.github.io/)